# how would i get the enemy to avoid the characters line at all costs while still trying to eliminate him

Tags: python, pygame

How would I get the enemy to avoid the characters line at all costs while still trying to eliminate him? The code I have as far makes the enemy run straight to the player and die pretty much straight away.

Does anyone have any idea how to keep the enemy from touching the players line?

Here is the code:

```
import random 
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *
import time

GREEN=(0,125,0)
BLUE=(0,0,125)

Yplayer = 225/2
Xplayer = 350

playerlinesavedata = []
playercurrent = []

Xplayerchange=0
Yplayerchange=0

Yenemy = 450
Xenemy = 300

enemylinesavedata = []
enemycurrent = []

Xenemychange=0
Yenemychange=0

windowX = 900
windowY = 600

pygame.init()
DISPLAY=pygame.display.set_mode((windowX,windowY),0,32)


def enemymovement():
    global Xplayer,Yplayer,Xenemy,Yenemy
    enemy1 = True
    enemydirection = random.randint(1,4)
    
    # enemy moves toward player
    if Xenemy > Xplayer: enemydirection = 1
    elif Xenemy < Xplayer: enemydirection = 2
    elif Yenemy > Yplayer: enemydirection = 3
    elif Yenemy < Yplayer: enemydirection = 4

    while enemy1 == True:    
        if enemydirection == 1:
            Xenemychange= -random.randint(1,4)
            Xenemy+=Xenemychange
            
        if enemydirection == 2:
            Xenemychange= random.randint(1,4)
            Xenemy+=Xenemychange
            
        if enemydirection == 3:            
            Yenemychange= -random.randint(1,4)
            Yenemy+=Yenemychange
            
        if enemydirection == 4:
            Yenemychange= random.randint(1,4)            
            Yenemy+=Yenemychange
            
        enemylinesavedata.append([Xenemy,Yenemy])
        enemy()
        break
            
def enemy():
    for XnY in enemylinesavedata:
        pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAY,BLUE, [XnY[0],XnY[1],5,5])

def player():
    for XnY in playerlinesavedata:
        pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAY,GREEN,[XnY[0],XnY[1],5,5])

def main():

    global playerlinesavedata, enemylinesavedata
    global Xplayer, Yplayer, Xenemy, Yenemy
    WHITE = (255,255,255)
    size = 5

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    while True:
        clock.tick(60)
        
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type==QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        Xplayer += (keys[pygame.K_d] - keys[pygame.K_a]) * size
        Yplayer += (keys[pygame.K_s] - keys[pygame.K_w]) * size
       
        playerlinesavedata.append((Xplayer, Yplayer))
        enemymovement()

        player_rectlist = [pygame.Rect(x, y, size, size) for x, y in playerlinesavedata]
        enemy_rectlist = [pygame.Rect(x, y, size, size) for x, y in enemylinesavedata]

        if player_rectlist[-1].collidelist(enemy_rectlist) >= 0:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

        if enemy_rectlist[-1].collidelist(player_rectlist) >= 0:
            playerlinesavedata = []
            Yplayer = 225//2
            Xplayer = 350
            enemylinesavedata = []
            Yenemy = 450
            Xenemy = 300
       
        DISPLAY.fill(WHITE)
        player()
        enemy()
        pygame.display.update()
   

main()
```

Answer (score 2):

It is a bad practice to use globalize variables. It is much better to use python classes as the pygame objects.

**Here is a cleaned up version of your code so that you or other users on Stack Overflow can help you with your problem more easily:**

```
import random 
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *
import time

pygame.init()

GREEN = (0, 125, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 125)
WHITE = (255,255,255)

windowX = 900
windowY = 600

wn = pygame.display.set_mode((windowX, windowY), 0, 32)

class Object:
    def __init__(self, X, Y, enemy=False, color=GREEN):
        self.enemy = enemy
        self.X = X
        self.Y = Y
        self.current = []
        self.Xchange = 0
        self.Ychange = 0
        self.direction = 0
        self.rectlist = []
        self.color = color
        self.size = 5

    def movement(self):
        for rect in self.rectlist:
            pygame.draw.rect(wn, self.color, rect)

        if self.enemy:
            if self.X > player.X:
                self.direction = 1
            elif self.X < player.X:
                self.direction = 2
            elif self.Y > player.Y:
                self.direction = 3
            elif self.Y < player.Y:
                self.direction = 4
  
            if self.direction == 1:
                self.Xchange = -random.randint(1,4)
                self.X += self.Xchange
                
            if self.direction == 2:
                self.Xchange = random.randint(1,4)
                self.X += self.Xchange
                
            if self.direction == 3:
                self.Ychange = -random.randint(1,4)
                self.Y += self.Ychange
                
            if self.direction == 4:
                self.Ychange = random.randint(1,4)
                self.Y += self.Ychange
        else:
            keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
            player.X += (keys[pygame.K_d] - keys[pygame.K_a]) * player.size
            player.Y += (keys[pygame.K_s] - keys[pygame.K_w]) * player.size
                    
        self.rectlist.append(pygame.Rect(self.X, self.Y, self.size, self.size))


player = Object(350, 225 / 2)
enemy = Object(450, 300, enemy=True, color=BLUE)


def main():
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    size = 5
    while True:
        clock.tick(60)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

        player.movement()
        enemy.movement()

        if player.rectlist[-1].collidelist(enemy.rectlist) >= 0:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

        if enemy.rectlist[-1].collidelist(player.rectlist) >= 0:
            player.rectlist = []
            player.X = 350
            player.Y = 225 // 2
            enemy.rectlist = []
            enemy.X = 450
            enemy.Y = 300
            
        pygame.display.update()
        wn.fill(WHITE)

main()
```

Here is my implementation of how to let the enemy avoid the player, ***though it is very buggy***, as in, ***it will go through the player's line
most of the time***:

```
import random 
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *
import time

pygame.init()

GREEN = (0, 125, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 125)
WHITE = (255,255,255)

windowX = 900
windowY = 600

wn = pygame.display.set_mode((windowX, windowY), 0, 32)

class Object:
    def __init__(self, X, Y, enemy=False, color=GREEN):
        self.enemy = enemy
        self.X = X
        self.Y = Y
        self.current = []
        self.Xchange = 0
        self.Ychange = 0
        self.direction = 0
        self.rectlist = []
        self.color = color
        self.size = 5
        self.bounce = 0

    def movement(self):
        for rect in self.rectlist:
            pygame.draw.rect(wn, self.color, rect)

        if self.enemy:
            enemydirection = random.randint(1,4)
            if not self.bounce:
                if self.X > player.X:
                    self.direction = 1
                elif self.X < player.X:
                    self.direction = 2
                elif self.Y > player.Y:
                    self.direction = 3
                elif self.Y < player.Y:
                    self.direction = 4
            else:
                self.bounce -= 1
            if self.direction == 1:
                self.Xchange = -random.randint(1,4)
                self.X += self.Xchange
                
            if self.direction == 2:
                self.Xchange = random.randint(1,4)
                self.X += self.Xchange
                
            if self.direction == 3:
                self.Ychange = -random.randint(1,4)
                self.Y += self.Ychange
                
            if self.direction == 4:
                self.Ychange = random.randint(1,4)
                self.Y += self.Ychange
        else:
            keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
            player.X += (keys[pygame.K_d] - keys[pygame.K_a]) * player.size
            player.Y += (keys[pygame.K_s] - keys[pygame.K_w]) * player.size
                    
        self.rectlist.append(pygame.Rect(self.X, self.Y, self.size, self.size))


player = Object(350, 225 / 2)
enemy = Object(450, 300, enemy=True, color=BLUE)


def main():
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    size = 5
    while True:
        clock.tick(60)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

        player.movement()
        enemy.movement()

        if player.rectlist[-1].collidelist(enemy.rectlist) >= 0:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

        if enemy.rectlist[-1].collidelist(player.rectlist) >= 0:
            if not enemy.bounce:
                while enemy.rectlist[-1].collidelist(player.rectlist) >= 0:
                    enemy.rectlist.pop()
                    enemy.rectlist.pop()
                    enemy.rectlist.pop()

                enemy.X, enemy.Y = enemy.rectlist[-1].x, enemy.rectlist[-1].y
                enemy.direction = enemy.direction - 2 if enemy.direction - 2 else enemy.direction + 2
                enemy.bounce = 40
        
            
        pygame.display.update()
        wn.fill(WHITE)

main()
```

Output:

[image]